# HTTPD/apache 2.4: strange problem with alias

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration

On httpd 2.4

```
alias /repo /repos
<Location /repos>
Require ip 192.168.0.7
</Location>
```

I can reach repos but not repo (403 forbidden). If I use `directory` instead of `location` nothing changes. 
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
Need options indexes
correct syntax

```
alias /repo /var/www/htdocs/repos
<Location /repos>
Require ip 192.168.0.7
</Location>
<Location /repo>
options indexes
Require ip 192.168.0.7
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to apache [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) documentation:

```
   Description: Maps URLs to filesystem locations
   Syntax:  Alias URL-path file-path|directory-path
```

You should define alias like:

```
   alias /repo /absolute/path/to/repos
```

If `/absolute/path/to/repos` is outside `DocumentRoot`, you should specify additional `<Directory>` sections which cover the destination of aliases.

Here is a useful [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527832/host-file-redirect-for-download-another-file/527837#527837) on how to remap url using: RewriteRule, Alias or Redirect